# How to cycle through a small set of options within a for loop?

Tags: bash

I have a bunch of jobs I need to submit to a job queue.  The queue has 8 different machines I can pick from or I can submit to any available server.  Sometimes a server may be faulty so I would like to be able to loop through available servers I send my jobs to.  A barebones version is below

```
# jobscript.sh
dir='some/directory/of/files/to/process'
for fn in $(ls $dir); do
    submit_job -q server@machine -x python script.py $fn
done
```

If I don't care what machine the job is sent to I remove the `@machine` portion so the command is just `submit_job -q server -x python script.py $fn`.

If I do want to specify the specific machine then I specify which machine by appending a number after `machine` as  `server@machine1` then on the next iteration `server@machine2` then `server@machine2` etc.  The output of the script would then look like the following if I only use the first 3 servers

```
submit_job -q server@machine1 -x python script.py file1
submit_job -q server@machine2 -x python script.py file2
submit_job -q server@machine3 -x python script.py file3
submit_job -q server@machine1 -x python script.py file4
submit_job -q server@machine2 -x python script.py file5
submit_job -q server@machine3 -x python script.py file6
submit_job -q server@machine1 -x python script.py file7
submit_job -q server@machine2 -x python script.py file8
...
```

The list of available servers is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]` but I would like to additionally specify from the command line a list of servers to ignore so something like

```
$bash jobscript.sh -skip 1,4,8
```

which would only cycle through `2, 3, 5, 6, 7` and product the output

```
submit_job -q server@machine2 -x python script.py file1
submit_job -q server@machine3 -x python script.py file2
submit_job -q server@machine5 -x python script.py file3
submit_job -q server@machine6 -x python script.py file4
submit_job -q server@machine7 -x python script.py file5
submit_job -q server@machine2 -x python script.py file6
submit_job -q server@machine3 -x python script.py file7
submit_job -q server@machine5 -x python script.py file8
submit_job -q server@machine6 -x python script.py file8
...
```

if flag `-skip` is not present, just run the command without `@machine` which will allow the queue to decide where to place the job and the commands look like

```
submit_job -q server -x python script.py file1
submit_job -q server -x python script.py file2
submit_job -q server -x python script.py file3
submit_job -q server -x python script.py file4
submit_job -q server -x python script.py file5
submit_job -q server -x python script.py file6
submit_job -q server -x python script.py file7
submit_job -q server -x python script.py file8
submit_job -q server -x python script.py file8
...
```

Comment: can't you just add an if statement inside your for loop to check if you should skip a certain variable?

Comment: Not directly related to the question but have a look at [why parsing the output of `ls` is bad](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso I'm not sure what you mean, the for loop iterates over files that are arguments to the python script.  Can you provide an example?

Comment: First make an array of machines and delete those that you want to skip. Iterate through array.

Comment: @WalterA how do you cycle through them? I would also prefer to not hard code this array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do *most* of the work for you:

```
#!/bin/bash

machines=(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)
skip_arr=(1 4 8)
declare -a arr
for i in "${machines[@]}"; do
    if [[ ! " ${skip_arr[@]} " =~ " $i " ]]; then
        arr+=($i)
    fi
done
arr_len="${#arr[@]}"
declare -i i=0
for f in $(ls); do
    i="i % arr_len"
    echo "file is $f, machine is $i"
    let i++
done
```

Right now, I've set it up to go through the current directory, and just echo the values of the machine and filename. Obviously you'll want to change this to actually execute the commands from the right directory.

The last thing you need to do is build up `skip_arr` from the command line input, and then check if it's empty when you're executing your command.

Hopefully this gets you most of the way there. Let me know if you have any questions about anything I've done here.

Answer (score 1):

Cycle through array of machines

```
#!/bin/bash

rotate() {
   if [[ "$1" = "all" ]]; then
      machines=(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)
   else
      machines=($*)
   fi

   idx=0
   max=${#machines[@]}

   for ((fn=0; fn<20; fn++)); do
      if (( $max > 0 )); then
         servernr=${machines[idx]}
         ((idx=(idx+1) % ${max}))
      else
         servernr=""
      fi
      echo "submit -q server${servernr} file${fn}"
   done
}

# test
echo "Rotate 0 machines"
rotate
echo "Rotate all machines"
rotate all
echo "Rotate some machines"
rotate 2 5 6
```